# Update a table foreign keys by substituting by a lookup from the result of another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables :

Table 1:

```
SELECT * FROM ORIGINAL_DEALER;

    ID ENAME

----- --------------------------
    1 JOHN
    2 00000JOHN
    3 JACK
    4 00000JACK
    5 MARIA
    6 00000MARIA
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES;

ID_NUM
------
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

1. I'll have to update `NAMES`.
2. Table `ORIGINAL_DEALER` has duplicate / invalid names such as
   `00000JOHN`
       The invalid names have exactly five zeros prefixed before the valid names.     i.e valid name:  `JOHN`
        invalid name:  `00000JOHN`
3. Now I'll have to select the ID's of invalid names from
   `ORIGINAL_DEALER` table and update the `ID_NUM` in `NAMES` table
   WITH VALID ID.  i.e when the invalid `ename= '00000JOHN'` has an `ID
   = 2` which is also invalid. but original_dealer is parent table, i'll have to replace all the invalid id's in NAMES table with valid
   ones.

i.e the output after updating NAMES should be:

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES;

ID_NUM
------
 1
 1
 3
 3
 5
 5
```

How can I do it without manually setting it everytime as there will huge data?
I'm using Oracle DB

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: You can use Inner query..

Comment: Are the values in column ENAME unique ? I presume not since I assume ID to be the primary key, and ENAME a data field. Is the "wrong" and the "correct" name always listed as records with one value differing in ID ? Is the wrong name always one value of ID higher ?

Comment: yup.. ID in Original_dealer is primary key and id_num is foreign key referencing ID in Original_dealer.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience , i was working on this for two days.

Comment: i tried the following query. But it throws an error saying:- virtual column not allowed here.

Comment: the query i tried out was :- " UPDATE (SELECT NAMES.ID_NUM AS OLD,A.ID AS NEW,A.ENAME
FROM NAMES FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT A2.ID,A2.ENAME,ID_NUM FROM ORIGINAL_DEALER A1,ORIGINAL_DEALER A2 ,NAMES N1 WHERE A1.ENAME=CONCAT('00000',A2.ENAME) AND N1.ID_NUM=A1.ID) A ON NAMES.ID_NUM=A.ID_NUM) K SET K.OLD=K.NEW WHERE K.NEW IS NOT NULL; "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a update statement with a lookup like below, by using an inner lookup subquery which in turn uses the [TRIM](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreftrimfunc.html) function to strip out the leading zeroes during matching. We also restrict the update to just those `Names` linked to `OriginalDealer` records starting with `00000` to mimimize the risk of unnecessary updates.

```
UPDATE Names SET ID_NUM = 
(SELECT od1.ID
 FROM OriginalDealer od1
      INNER JOIN OriginalDealer od2
      ON od1.EName = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM od2.EName)
 WHERE od2.ID = Names.ID_NUM)
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM OriginalDealer od
  WHERE od.ENAME LIKE '00000%'
  AND Names.ID_NUM =  od.ID
);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f87e83/6)

Note that the model of marking duplicates with a prefix like '00000' is rather fragile:

- It assumes there is exactly 1 match between the `00000NAME` and `NAME` rows in `ORIGINAL_DEALER`
- If the above isn't true, it will attempt to set `Names.ID_NUM` to NULL or Fail if there is more than one match (which is probably a good thing, we don't want to corrupt data)

Comment: Thank you StuartLC.. it works completely fine.. Thanks a lot :)